# How to change a block of text on a website each time when nav item is clicked with JS/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I'd like for the text in the greenish rectangle to change each time different nav link in the navbar (purple rect) is clicked.

Currently I have different .html files that change them, but I would like for the page not to refresh each time and just to substitute the text since everything on the page stays the same to decrease load time and resources. Thanks!

[see website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbftM.jpg)

Each block of text is a section in html:

```
<section class="facts">
        <p><span class="underlined">Some random Franka facts:</span>
            <ul>
                <li>I know how to play piano and cello (I may have forgotten cello a bit, tbh…)</li>
                <li>Can’t live without a cup of coffee first thing in the morning</li>
                <li>Strongly resent waking up too early (but will do it for travels and if you lure me with coffee smell)</li>
                <li>I spend a ridiculous amount of time watching (yes, watching) League of Legends Championship (I play it as well)</li>
                <li>I am extremely happy that my name anagram is Krafna (=donut in Croatian)</li>
                <li>I like donuts</li>
                <li>I like red wine and craft beer</li>
                <li>I like writing scientific/research papers and organising conferences</li>
                <li>I love Simon Sinek</li>
                <li>I've always liked psychodelic everything (including websites ~ can you tell?)</li>
                <li>Purple is my favorite color</li>
            </ul>
        </p>

        <p>If I had to describe myself in 3 words it would be: courageous. wanderluster. open. </p>

        <p><span class="underlined">What I always wanted to do but never started (yet):</span>
            <ul>
                <li>write articles on Medium</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </section>
```

So for example when clicked on Facts I want to trigger the text above, when clicked on Knowledge, a different text etc. The text is always on the same position.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some code with this. And for the text change, you could use javascript for this of course.

Comment: @JohannesPiontkowitz thanks, just did!

Comment: Did you try anything regarding js/jquery?

Comment: @JohannesPiontkowitz I've searched a lot for the answer to this, but still couldn't find it. What I did find wasn't applicable for this situation, and even though I know how I would change a text with a button or within the button itself, I don't know how to make that clicking a nav item triggers changed section text (still learning js..).

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript/jquery to achieve this. I used jquery in this solution.

HTML:

```
<!-- These elements resemble your navbar items  -->
<li id="button1">
Listelement that triggers Fact #1
</li>
<br>
<button id="button2">
Button that triggers Fact #2
</button>
<br>
<a id="button3">
Anchor that triggers Fact #3
</a><br>
<section class="facts" id="fact1">
        <p><span class="underlined">Some random Franka facts:</span>
            TEXTBLOCK #1
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="facts" id="fact2">
        <p><span class="underlined">Some random Franka facts:</span>
            TEXTBLOCK #2
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="facts" id="fact3">
        <p><span class="underlined">Some random Franka facts:</span>
            TEXTBLOCK #3
        </p>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.facts{
  display:none;
}

.active{
  display:block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('.facts').removeClass('active');
  $('#fact1').addClass('active');
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
    $('.facts').removeClass('active');
  $('#fact2').addClass('active');
});

$('#button3').click(function(){
    $('.facts').removeClass('active');
  $('#fact3').addClass('active');
});

// change the button ids to your navbar link ids
```

[Working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7vLot9ju/)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to apply it on my website! Thanks a lot for your fast answer :)